# How to incorporate a datepicker in an innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a php page that reads data from a Mysql table and displays it in a HTML table.  I then use AJAX to allow the user to update the data, one row at a time.  For text fields, that works fine.

However, one of the columns is a date.  I would really like the user to select the date from something like JQuery’s datepicker but I cannot figure out how to do it.

The initial data table has the following line to display the current date field:

```
echo "<td><div id=$eventdate_id>$row[eventdate]</div></td>";
```

I then modify this line using Javascript to make a field the user can edit:

```
document.getElementById(eventdate_id).innerHTML = "<input type=text id='" +data_eventdate + "' value='"+ eventdate + "'>";
```

Part of my problem is that the datepicker uses the id of the HTML element but I am already using it…

Any idea how I can add the datepicker?

Thanks

Comment: Give it a unique ID? Append something to that ID so that it remains unique in the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/, after you set the innerHTML you could do it like this:

```
$( "#"+data_eventdate ).datepicker();
```

Or you could add a class to the input (`<input class="date_input" type=...`) and add datepickers to all of them in one go:

```
$( ".date_input" ).datepicker();
```

You can include options in the individual `datepicker( {/*options here*/} )` calls, or you can set defaults for all datepickers at the start of your code with `$.datepicker.setDefaults()` (example from [datepicker documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-setDefaults)):

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
  showOn: "both",
  buttonImageOnly: true,
  buttonImage: "calendar.gif",
  buttonText: "Calendar"
});
```

Comment: Sorry but where would the $( ".date_input" ).datepicker(); line go?

Comment: Any time after you've created your input(s), but you need to have added the class to them.

Comment: I put in the $( "#"+data_eventdate ).datepicker(); line immediately after innerHTML line and the datepicker appeared when I clicked inside the date field on the page. However, it did not pick up the datepicker options I had set at the start of the page (these options are picked up when I use id="datepicker" but I can't here) and the date I selected was not saved to the database (if I just type the date it saves fine). Any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: I presume you're setting options on an individual datepicker instance rather than setting the defaults - added more info to the answer

Comment: oh, missed the bit about the DB... That's a bit hard to guess at - are the dates coming out in the same format? Can you look in the network debugger of whatever browser you're using and see if the values are being sent correctly/at all?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an issue with the `id`, but I think it would be better to use a class. Then you can convert all of the dates to input elements and instrument them with datepickers all at once.

```
echo "<td><div class='date'>$row[eventdate]</div></td>";
```

You can then use:

```
$('.date').html(function(i, date) {
    // The "date" parameter is the current text inside the div.

    // Create the input element.
    var $input = $('<input type="text"/>').val(date);

    // Instrument the input element with a datepicker.
    $input.datepicker();

    // Return the input element so it is placed in the div.
    return $input;
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j7jo7vms/1/)